# The Undeletable Oracle APEX Cookie

Tags: javascript, oracle-apex

I am working on SSO using CPIP for Oracle APEX. I can get SSO working once, but it won't work after the user logs out unless they delete their cookies. To fix this, I'm creating a custom logout page inside the application (to avoid any domain restrictions) that will delete the cookies. The particular one I'm trying to delete is called ORA_WWV_APP_109. Mozilla Developer Tools Storage lists the following properties.

```
CreationTime:"Tue, 27 Mar 2018 15:22:45 GMT"
Domain:"dev-banner01.cameron.edu"
Expires:"Session"
HostOnly:true
HttpOnly:true
LastAccessed:"Tue, 27 Mar 2018 15:40:08 GMT"
Path:"/pls/apex/"
Secure:false
```

I tried the following JavaScript.

```
document.cookie="ORA_WWV_APP_109=;path=/pls/apex/;HttpOnly;expires=Thu, 01-Jan-1970 00:00:01 GMT;";
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't work. Can anyone tell me why?

Thank you,

~ Bob

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the answer. Because it's an httpOnly cookie, it can only be modified via an HTTP header.